# mongodb/mongoose returning empty array when finding all

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm writing a Node.js backend for an existing mongodb Atlas cluster.

In my routes when I run

```
const routes = (app) => {
    app.route('/file')
        .get((req, res, next) => {
            console.log('request from : ' + req.originalUrl)
            console.log('request type : ' + req.method)
            next();
        }, getFiles);
}
```

where `getFiles` is as follows:

```
const ChronicFile = mongoose.model('File', FileSchema);
export const getFiles = (req, res) => {
    ChronicFile.find({}, (err, chronicFile) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        console.log(chronicFile);
        res.json(chronicFile);
    });
}
```

I get a blank array returned:

```
ur server running on port4000
request from : /file
request type : GET
[]
```

The db structure according to the mongodb shell is the overall db titled `Chronic` and three collections titled `Chronic Files`, `fs.chunks`, and `fs.files`. My goal is to query the fs.files collection and get everything from there.

The scheme within the `fs.files` collections is as follows:

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"604e57219ffdaa7e11a8edad"
   },
   "length":{
      "$numberLong":"3163108"
   },
   "chunkSize":261120,
   "uploadDate":{
      "$date":"2021-03-14T18:34:10.586Z"
   },
   "filename":"4-dance-a-complex.mp3",
   "metadata":{
      
   }
}
```

and my mongoose schema is as follows:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

export const FileSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
    },
    chunkSize : {
        type: Number
    },
    fileName : {
        type: String
    },
    length: {
        type: Number
    },
    metadata : {
        type: Object
    },
    uploadDate : {
        type: Date
    }
}, { collection : 'Chronic.fs.files'});
```

I added the collection name as shown above because I looked through previous stackoverflow posts and they had a naming problem. Is there something wrong I'm doing here or am I missing something else? When I do `db.getName()` on the mongo shell it shows `Chronic` and when I do `db.fs.files.find()` it does output all the entries within that collection.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was within this chunk of code:

```
const ChronicFile = mongoose.model('File', FileSchema);
export const getFiles = (req, res) => {
    ChronicFile.find({}, (err, chronicFile) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        console.log(chronicFile);
        res.json(chronicFile);
    });
}
```

I needed to pass in the actual collections name into the mongoose model, rather than just `File`